# Использование многопоточности в методе и winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Осваиваю шарп и пишу для себя приложение, которое чистит захламленные директории. Реализовал так, что при нажатии кнопки "Старт", переменная Data.IsStart принимала значение true и программа начинала таскать файлы,а при нажатии клавиши "Стоп", Data.IsStart принимала значение false и перенос файлов останавливался. После нажатия клавиши "Старт" WinForm зависает, т.к. метод зацикливается. Понимаю, что для исправления данной проблемы нужно использовать многопоточность, но не знаю как грамотно это реализовать. Прошу Вашей помощи.

```
public static void DoStart()
    {

        try
        {
            while (Data.IsStart)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<string> filesname = Directory.GetFiles(Data.FormatAndPath["dir"]).ToList<string>();
                    foreach (string file in filesname)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(file))
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> format in Data.FormatAndPath)
                            {
                                FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(file);
                                if (fileInf.Extension.Contains(format.Key) && !format.Key.Equals("dir"))
                                {
                                    fileInf.MoveTo(format.Value + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_") + fileInf.Name);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException) { }
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте начнём с код-ревью и рефакторинга.

Я переписал ваш метод следующим образом:

```
public static void MoveFiles()
{
    try
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Data.Path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            foreach (var format in Data.Formats)
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fileInfo.Extension.Contains(format.Key))
                {
                    fileInfo.MoveTo(format.Value + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_") + fileInfo.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException) { }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }
}
```

Изменил имя метода: теперь оно соответствует выполняемым действиям.
Убрал цикл `while` - он абсолютно не нужен. Из-за него цикл перемещения файлов выполняется постоянно.
Вызов `ToList` избыточен.
Добавил в класс `Data` свойство `string Path`, содержащее именно путь. Словарь с форматами переименовал в `Formats` и убрал из него ключ `dir`. Благодаря этому упростилась проверка в операторе `if`.
Убрал проверку `File.Exists`. Нет смысла проверять наличие файла, который был получен парой строк выше. А главное, эта проверка всё равно не спасёт если файл будет удалён (пользователем или другим процессом) *после* проверки и *до* вызова `MoveTo`. Отсутствие файла будет перехвачено блоком `catch (IOException)` (при желании можно добавить `catch (FileNotFoundException)`).

И должен ли метод быть `public` и `static`? Я не знаю, где он у вас расположен.

---

Теперь нужно запустить код в отдельном потоке, а главное - *грамотно* сделать отмену его выполнения.

Я не вижу определения `Data.IsStart`, но сильно подозреваю, что у него отсутствует модификатор [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Без него код может сломаться. Как повезёт...

Использование булевой переменной хоть и возможно, но лучше взять современные средства: [токен отмены](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8).

Добавляем в класс формы поле

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
```

В обработчиках кнопок пишем:

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Run(() => MoveFiles(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
}

private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
}
```

Сигнатуру нашего метода меняем на следующую:

```
void MoveFiles(CancellationToken token)
```

И в теле метода проверяем токен:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;

    foreach (var format in Data.Formats)
```

---

По поводу распараллеливания самого копирования файлов (`Parallel.ForEach` и т. п.). Вряд ли это имеет смысл, т. к. накопитель-то один. И пока он будет обрабатывать запрос на перемещение файла из одного потока, другие потоки будут ждать. C HDD это точно так. Однако, по слухам, в случае SSD распараллеливание имеет смысл. Нужно пробовать.

Comment: Невнимателен, нашел ответ про путь, старый коммент удалил. Спасибо Вам за ревью и рефракторинг. Ожидаю продолжения)

Comment: @Rumeet94 - дописал ответ.

Comment: @Rumeet94 - если возникнет желание сделать прогресс перемещения файлов - задавайте новый вопрос. Не спрашивайте такое в комментах.

Comment: @Rumeet94 - А вообще, т. к. копирование файлов - это IO-bound операция, то правильнее это делать асинхронно, вместо запуска отдельного потока/задачи.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, работает. Но есть один ньюанс. Я хочу чтобы файлы перемещались постоянно, пока не будет нажата клавиша "Cтоп". Для решения данной проблемы как я понял лучше завести отдельную задачу? И вопрос не по теме, с вами можно как-то связаться в лс или только через задачи?

Comment: @Rumeet94 - _чтобы файлы перемещались постоянно_ - ну тогда верните на место цикл `while`. И либо пишите `while(true)`, либо `while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)`, при этом уберите `if` из `foreach`.

Comment: @Rumeet94 - никаких лс. Я глупый и малограмотный: спросите меня о чём-то, а я не знаю ответ. Всё, приплыли... Лучше спрашивайте сразу у всех - кто-нибудь да ответит.

Answer (score 0):

Саму функцию, чтобы интерфейс не вис, можно запускать с помощью такой конструкции:

```
...
new Thread(DoStart()).Start();
...
```

что создаст новый поток, который будет выполнять функцию `DoStart()`

Сам же перенос файлов тоже можно очень легко распараллелить:

```
public static void DoStart()
    {

        try
        {
            while (Data.IsStart)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<string> filesname = Directory.GetFiles(Data.FormatAndPath["dir"]).ToList<string>();
                    Parallel.ForEach(filesname, (file) =>
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(file))
                            Parallel.ForEach(Data.FormatAndPath, (format) =>
                            {
                                FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(file);
                                if (fileInf.Extension.Contains(format.Key) && !format.Key.Equals("dir"))
                                {
                                    fileInf.MoveTo(format.Value + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_") + fileInf.Name);
                                }
                            });
                    });
                }
                catch (IOException) { }
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }

    }
```

Главное подключить эти неймспейсы:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но хотел еще уточнить:                                                                               
 private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Data.IsStart = true;
            tbDir.ReadOnly = true;
            new Thread(() => Handler.DoStart()).Start();
        }     При выходе из метода, поток погибает или его нужно будет самому отключать?

Comment: @Rumeet94 да, выглядит нормально)

Comment: поправил комментарий выше, посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: @Rumeet94 - Э-э-э... подождите мой ответ. Я подробно распишу проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ожидаю, спасибо за отклик)